# Multiple times same data is showing in Select 2 dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a select box in my update form with different payment type. I need to select multiple data. If user already have payment type in table then fetch the data and load in selectbox. I have added these feature but in dropdown multiple times data is showing. Please find the image I have attached.

[image]

Actually user have three payment type. The dropdown shows these payment type in three times.

Please check the code given below and correct me.

`$cabin->payment_type = payment type from user table`

`$cabinInfo->paymentType() = Generating array in controller`

**update.blade.php**

```
@inject('cabinInfo', 'App\Http\Controllers\Cabinowner\DetailsController')
    <select id="payment" name="payment" class="form-control payment" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose payment type" style="width: 100%;">
       @foreach($cabin->payment_type as $payment)
          @foreach($cabinInfo->paymentType() as $paymentTypeKey => $paymentType)
             <option value="{{ $paymentTypeKey }}" @if($paymentTypeKey == $payment || old('payment') == $payment) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $paymentType }}</option>
          @endforeach
       @endforeach
</select>
```

**script**

```
/* Multiple select for payment */
$(".payment").select2();
```

**UpdateController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $cabin       = Cabin::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->first();
    return view('update', ['cabin' => $cabin]);
}


public function paymentType()
{
    $array = array(
        '0' => "Cash",
        '1' => "Debit Card",
        '2' => "Credit Card",
    );

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Is $cabin a Model?  Is `payment_type` a db column? Or a relationship?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips, I forgot to add controller file in my question. Now I have included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `$cabin->payment_type` returns an array?  If so Your logic should more like this:

```
@inject('cabinInfo', 'App\Http\Controllers\Cabinowner\DetailsController')
    <select id="payment" name="payment" class="form-control payment" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose payment type" style="width: 100%;">
        @foreach($cabinInfo->paymentType() as $paymentTypeKey => $paymentType)
           <option value="{{ $paymentTypeKey }}" @if(in_array($paymentTypeKey, $cabin->payment_type )|| in_array(old('payment'), $cabin->payment_type )) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $paymentType }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: $cabin->payment_type is not a string it is an array payment_type: {0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2"}

Comment: @samsam what is the significance of the values in payment_type?  The reason you have each option 3 times in your drop down is your outer FOR loop is iterating over the 3 payment_types, and for each one it is writing out all the $cabinInfo->paymentType().  So you need to remove the outer FOR loop.  I don't know the purpose of the $cabin->payment_type so can not give advice on how to use.  maybe you can explain that some more.

Comment: I will explain. Eg: In a table there is a hotel, this hotel has field `patment_type`, this field value is array `{0:"0", 1:"1"}`. `0 is cash and 1 is creditcard`. I have a form to update hotel details. I need to select a new payment type from dropdown and update the table. If I select `creditcard` from dropdown and update then the result would be `{0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2"}` in table.

Comment: Okay I assume the keys in that array don't matter, just the values.  EG you could see  {0:"2", 1: "1"}